# Times New Roman on Linux

Tags: fonts, linux, times

I need your helps, I have written my thesis on Linux and I have used Texmaker, but i have a problem, I can not change font to Times New Roman

I have searched on Google, people usually said that uses following code blog. But it does not solve my problem

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times Roman}
```

Please help me.

Comment: `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` will possibly be helpful.

Comment: @Bernard Is there some reason for the comment in French?

Comment: @Bernard You can delete the comment and repost in English, editing is time-limited for users. (Oh, and Joseph probably wasn't notified of that comment, as you didn't write `@JosephWright`.)

Comment: The precise commands should be `usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman}` (for a Windows system. A font manager will give you the exact family name on yours). For maths, as suggested by @Harish Kumar, `usepackage{newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of fonts based on the original Times Roman. On Linux run

```
fc-list | grep Times | grep ".otf"
```

or

```
fc-list | grep Times | grep ".ttf"
```

for a TrueType version. If you do not get any output then you do not have a ttf or otf variant of Times installed. If you get an output then it will list the symbolic name of the font. On my system:

```
voss@shania:~> fc-list | grep Times | grep ".otf"
/home/voss/.fonts/Times/TimesNewRomanPSStd-Bold.otf: Times New Roman PS Std:style=Bold
/home/voss/.fonts/Times/TimesNewRomanPSStd-BoldIt.otf: Times New Roman PS Std:style=Bold Italic
/home/voss/.fonts/Times/TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT.otf: Times New Roman PS MT:style=Bold Italic
/home/voss/.fonts/Times/TimesNewRomanMTStd.otf: Times New Roman MT Std:style=Regular
...
```

To get more information about a specific font run for example:

```
voss@shania:~> otfinfo -i /home/voss/.fonts/Times/TimesNewRomanPSMT.otf
Family:              Times New Roman PS MT
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           TimesNewRomanPSMT
PostScript name:     TimesNewRomanPSMT
Preferred subfamily: Roman
Mac font menu name:  Times New Roman PS MT
Version:             OTF 1.0;PS 001.003;Core 1.0.22
Unique ID:           1.0;ADBE;TimesNewRomanPSMT
Trademark:           Please refer to the Copyright section for the font trademark attribution notices.
Copyright:           Copyright (c) 1988, 1990, 1993, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999 Adobe Systems Incorporated.  All Rights Reserved.Times New Roman is a trademark of the Monotype Corporation, registered in the US Patent and Trademark Office and may be registered in certain other jurisdictions.
Vendor ID:           ADBE
```

This version of Times I'll set with `\setmainfont{Times New Roman PS MT}`
 or using the PostScript name with `\setmainfont{TimesNewRomanPSMT}`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, right? If so, and if your TeX distribution is reasonably modern, the following two instructions should get you going on most systems, including a Linux system:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}
```